# Create command For creating Node in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I was going through Neo4j Manuals to get started with Neo4j.

So I installed Neo4j server and created my first node from the docs

```
CREATE (n:Actor { name:"Tom Hanks" });
```

As a node can have labels and properties. I interpreted the above query as
 creating a node with label Actor having one property name.
And n means we are creating a node.

Then I come across this query `CREATE (a { name : 'Andres' })`

But what is that a in create(a:...) , what that a means.

Cypher syntax looks a bit weird.

Comment: Cypher syntax & refcard http://neo4j.com/developer/cypher

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is `CREATE (variablename:Label {propertyname:"propertyValue"})`

The "n" in `CREATE (n:Actor { name:"Tom Hanks" })` does not mean you are creating a node, it is just a variable name here. You can use that variable name further on in the same query if you want.

In `CREATE (a { name : 'Andres' })`, the "a" is a variable name again. This time, a node is created without a label.

Comment: Hey David where I can get Cypher syntax

Comment: @MahtabAlam google "cypher syntax" and its your first hit. I am willing to help but you should put some effort into these things yourself as well ;)

Comment: Thanks David , one more thing when I execute " CREATE (Actor { name:"Tom Hanks" });" it says Created 1 node, set 1 property, returned 0 rows in 346 ms. Where is Label , I thought Actor is label here.

Comment: ok this is my last response here. You need the :Actor and not just Actor or else it will just be a variable name again

Comment: Hey David , I did search for cypher syntax .And I am reading from the neo4j manual.They have mentioned examples but not the exact syntax that create command follows.I was looking for  syntax like you mentioned above.That would be very helpful.